# Matroid for Laurent series

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, profinite-groups, matroid-theory

I am trying to find a matroid for profinite rings which are the inverse limit of their finite quotients, and whose linearly independent elements are of the form $L((t_1,\dots,t_n))$.

To set this up, let $X$ be a class of profinite rings and let $Y$ be a class of profinite algebras over elements of $X$. Assume that, if $R$ is in $X$ and $R$ is isomorphic to $S$, then $S$ is in $X$. Assume that, if $R$ is in $X$, then $R$ is in $Y$ when viewed as an $R$-algebra, and also that for each $R$-algebra $S$ in $Y$, $R$ is an element of $X$.

I am trying to devise further features of $X$ and $Y$ to the effect that there is a matroid $M$ where:

- For each $R$-algebra $S$ in $Y$, the "linearly independent" objects of the (infinite) matroid are Laurent series $R((t_1,\dots,t_n))$.
- For each $R$-algebra $S$ in $Y$, $S$ satisfies property $\phi(S)$ over $R((t_1,\dots,t_n))$, where $n$ is the maximal possible choice of integer such that this is possible. Alternatively, we could think of $R((S))$ where $S$ is a set of the largest possible cardinality. But we would probably have to deal with the case above first.
- We define $\psi(S)$ as a property of $R$-algebras $S$ that, along with $\phi$ in the above, produces an infinite matroid M.

Is it possible that this matroid and its features simply follow from the ordinary one, taking various profinite limits of quotients of all objects involved?

A similar idea ensues for $L[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$, which perhaps could come first.